# Remove trailing spaces in visual studio 2012

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I want to remove trailing spaces of each line from a text file, keeping the line breaks intact. I am using Visual studio 2012's Regex feature for this.

When I am trying to find `\s*\r?\n` and replace with `\r\n` it is also stripping out all the empty lines, which is not expected.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: `\s` matches newlines. Try using " " (space) instead.

Comment: I want to remove the \t and other possible space chars too.

Comment: Just make the `\s*` lazy then. `\s*?`

Comment: `\s+\r?\n` should do it

Comment: I've tried the following in vs12, and it seems to work: `[\t ]+\r?$`

Answer (score 8):

Set subtraction to the rescue!

```
[\s-[\n]]+\n
```

...or *any whitespace character* (`\s`) *except* (`-`) *linefeed* (`[\n]`).  Ordinarily, `-` is treated as either a range operator or a literal hyphen (depending on its position within the character class), and `[` is treated as a literal bracket.  But if the hyphen is followed by something that looks like a character class, it becomes a set subtraction operator.

ref: [Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction)

Comment: Nice - set subtraction - it is the first time I have seen someone using them :)

Comment: I keep forgetting it's available.  It's much more convenient than Java's set intersection (`[\s&&[^\n]]`), not mention easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you trying to match the carriage return `\r` and newline `\n` if you don't want them replaced and then replace everything with `\r\n`.

Instead match only the spaces and tabs and any other whitespace character that you want stripped and replace that with the empty string like this:

```
[ \t]*$
```

This will match zero or more spaces or tabs at the end of each line and replace them with the empty string.

NOTE: You will have to use multi-line mode so `$` matches at the end of every line.

If you can't activate multi-line mode in VS then you can use another expression that doesn't need that:

```
[ \t]*(?=\r?\n)
```

This will match zero or more tabs and spaces as long as they are followed by an optional carriage return then a newline or in other words, as long as they are at the end of line.

Comment: Multiline mode is usually the default in text editors.  I haven't used the new VS with real (.NET) regex support, but I would be very surprised if it isn't the case there, too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but i use the search and replace with regex of Visual Studio with this string (no quotes)
" +\r?$" and leave the replace field empty then just do replace all. This preserves the line breaks and works for the VS regex flavor.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me in SSMS 18, which is supposedly using VS shell.